# Attributes not valid when referencing another schema in the XSD

Tags: xml, validation, intellij-idea, xsd, xml-namespaces

I have two schemas:

```
<schema xmlns:foo="urn:x:foo:1.0" xmlns:bar="urn:x:bar:1.0"
        targetNamespace="urn:x:foo:1.0"
        version="1.0"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <element name="bar" type="bar:bar" />
</schema>
```

and

```
<schema xmlns:bar="urn:x:bar:1.0"
        targetNamespace="urn:x:bar:1.0"
        version="1.0"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <complexType name="bar">
        <attribute name="goo" type="string" />
    </complexType>
    <element name="bar" type="bar:bar"/>
</schema>
```

When editing XML in IntelliJ 15 (EAP), this XML validates well:

```
<bar goo="xxx" xmlns="urn:x:bar:1.0" />
```

but this cannot find attribute `goo` (while the element bar itself is fine):

```
<bar goo="xxx" xmlns="urn:x:foo:1.0" />
```

I've tried to add `<import namespace="urn:x:bar:1.0"/>` to `foo.xsd` but without success.

Is this a bug in IntelliJ or am I missing something? Would you recommend any (preferably online) XML validator capable of handling multiple XSD files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that this is probably a [bug in IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147443), as I can validate this using xmllint (I need to add `<import namespace="urn:x:bar:1.0" schemaLocation="bar.xsd"/>`).

Maybe a workaround can be to define complex type foo:bar that extends bar:bar - this way seems valid for IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

The xs:import is necessary. You could try adding a schemaLocation attribute on your xs:import - it is optional, but some XML processors do not have a default entity resolver for resolving a namespace to a schema location.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has built-in mapper.